# Можете ли проверить в чём ошибка моего кода?

Tags: python

Только начал изучать Python. Решил протестировать свою программу, ну банальный калькулятор, разные комбинации вводил, всё такое, решил добавить английский язык и тут началось самое интересное, при
первом вводе выбираем английский язык и тут пошло, вместо того, чтобы перейти на if с выбором английского языка он идёт последовательно, если кто может объясните, только пожалуйста понятным для новичка языком )

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: скинь текстом, так на вид - непонятно

Comment: Всё, что должно выполняться в блоке `if` при выполнении условия, должно идти с одинаковым отступом/табуляцией. Отступ кончился - тело `if`-а кончилось. У вас `if answer==` уже с неправильным отступом идёт.

Comment: Ещё любимая новичками ошибка с `or` при попытке сравнить переменную с несколькими значениями.

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В условиях нельзя указывать:
`if var==0 or 1 or 2 or 3`

Нужно указывать каждый раз упоминая проверяемую переменную, иначе будет ошибка.

Нужно написать: `if var==0 or var==1 or var==2 or var==3`. Здесь я каждый раз упомянул `var`.

Также, чтобы каждый раз не указывать в условии регистр, можно написать:

`var.lower()` и указать условие на нижний регистр, так как функция `lower()` переводит текст в нижний регистр, т.е.:

Условие: `if var.lower() == 'ru'`. Текст: 'rU'. Условие всё равно выполняется

Comment: `if var in (0, 1, 2, 3)`

Comment: Да, так тоже можно. Кстати, не знал такого способа. Спасибо

Comment: Спасибо за помощь ) в будущем не буду допускать таких ошибок

Comment: Не за что, @cwanniname =)

Answer (score 0):

На вид кажется, что Вам просто нужно ветвление if, то есть после выбора языка вам нужно писать не калькулятор, а ветвелние

```
if RU:
   калькулятор 
elif ENg:
   калькулятор
```

И да, после каждого if, если нужна зависимость от этого if, то вам нужно соблюдать табуляцию

Comment: Спасибо за помощь ) в будущем не буду допускать таких ошибок

Comment: Если Вам кто то помог, помечайте ответ зеленой галочкой